# Water Heater Two Cold Connections

Tags: water, water-heater

I am getting ready to finish our basement, which includes replacing our old hot water heater and moving it to a more logical location in the basement. The house was built in 2005 I have installed water heaters in the past, although I have never seen a hook up like this. I am not sure why there are two cold lines one for the 1st floor and one for the 2nd floor tied in like this.
[image]

Here is a picture of the new one, more logical location next to the sump instead of the middle of the room with an actual expansion tank
[image]

Comment: Was a handy place to put a tee for second floor/somewhere else?

Comment: That is my only thought, I suppose I could tie in both floors at the old location (2 90s u shape) and tee in off of one of the cold water lines down the line and make my new cpvc (h & c) runs over to the new heater.

Comment: That is the good thing about plumbing.  A couple of tees, an elbow or two and some straight pipe and have new lines.  Just need to make sure you don't mixed up the hot and cold.

Answer (score 7):

It is simply that the cold water feed for the second floor was implemented from that convenient spot and a convenient shut off valve for the whole thing.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

Found the plumber who did the installation when the house was built (shocked) he said it was just a good place to tie everything in. No circulator in this house that is for sure.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure there isn't a recirculating pump somewhere?

That's a common reason for "extra cold lines" on a water heater, with the "extra" being the return from recirculation.